# not able to drop and recreate the oracle text index

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-text

I am not able to drop and recreate the oracle text index.

```
SQL> drop index "WBR"."CTX_t1";

Index dropped

SQL> 
SQL> CREATE INDEX "WBR"."CTX_t1"
  2  ON WBR.t1(ASSET_XML)
  3  INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT"
  4  PARAMETERS ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DIRECT_DATASTORE SECTION GROUP CTXSYS.AUTO_SECTION_GROUP SYNC (every "SYSDATE+10/1440")')
  5  ;

CREATE INDEX "WBR"."CTX_t1"
ON WBR.t1(ASSET_XML)
INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT"
PARAMETERS ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DIRECT_DATASTORE SECTION GROUP CTXSYS.AUTO_SECTION_GROUP SYNC(every "SYSDATE+10/1440")')

ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10507: duplicate index name: CTX_t1
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
```

Even after dropping the cintext index, I can see the entry in CTXSYS.CTX_INDEXES.

The job and internal tables are still there in database:

```
DR$CTX_t1$I
DR$CTX_t1$J--job
DR$CTX_t1$K
DR$CTX_t1$N
DR$CTX_t1$R
DR$CTX_t1$X
```

any suggestions?

Comment: you need to commit the changes after dropping the index.

Comment: Does not help.Commit after issuing DDL?

Comment: Did you try to skip  " (quotes) ?

Comment: post the result of `select owner, object_name, object_type from dba_objects where upper(object_name) like '%CTX_T1%';`and your Oracle version, please. Are you connected with the user **WBR** or with other user?

Comment: I am not logged in as WBR user.
I am trying the above mentioned tasks from another schema ...
on facing errors...I even tried doing same stuff from DBA schema but failed.same error.

Answer (score 2):

1) check if there exists an other object with the same name (possible case insensitive)

```
select owner, object_name, object_type from dba_objects where upper(object_name) like '%CTX_T1%';
```

if yes drop it.

2) try drop the index with the FORCE option

```
drop index "WBR"."CTX_t1" FORCE;
```

if it doesn't help:

3) contact Oracle support

Comment: have tried FORCE clause as well.Even this was not working.Same error

Answer (score 2):

it seems a bug on oracle. We have a script who refresh our quality database from the production database. To solve this problem, we execute this PL/SQL script before refresh begin.

```
    /**
     * Correctif bug sur la suppression d'index full text: 
     * Unable to recreate an Oracle Text index as the database continually throws a "DRG-10507: duplicate index name" error
     * http://ask4dba.blogspot.com/2016/11/drg-10507-in-creating-text-index-after.html
     * https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/unable-recreate-oracle-text-index-database-continually-throws-drg-10507-duplicate-index-name-error
    **/
    DECLARE
      LR$IDX_ID NUMBER(15);
      LR$IDX_NAME VARCHAR2(255);
      LR$SCHEMA VARCHAR2(255);

    CURSOR C1 IS

            select IDX_ID, IDX_NAME, usr.USERNAME from CTXSYS.DR$INDEX
            join all_users usr on usr.USER_ID = IDX_OWNER#
            where IDX_NAME in ('IDX_EDI_EMISSION_MSG_EAI', 'IDX_EDI_EMISSION_MSG', 'IDX_EDI_RECEPTION_MSG', 'IDX_EDI_RECEPTION_MSG_TMS');

    BEGIN 

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('DEBUT de la suppression des index fulltext' );
        OPEN C1;
        LOOP 
            FETCH C1 INTO  LR$IDX_ID, LR$IDX_NAME, LR$SCHEMA;
            EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND; 

            BEGIN

                BEGIN

                    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Suppression (drop) de l''index '|| LR$SCHEMA || '.' || LR$IDX_NAME );
                    execute immediate 'DROP INDEX ' || LR$SCHEMA || '.' || LR$IDX_NAME;

                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN OTHERS THEN

                        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Erreur Oracle #'||TO_CHAR(SQLCODE)||' : '||SQLERRM(SQLCODE));
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('L''index ' || LR$IDX_NAME ||' n''existe pas :  ' || LR$IDX_ID);

                END;

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Suppression des lignes de l''index ' || LR$IDX_ID);
                delete from ctxsys.dr$index_value where IXV_IDX_ID = LR$IDX_ID;
                delete from ctxsys.dr$index_object where IXO_IDX_ID = LR$IDX_ID;
                delete from ctxsys.dr$index where idx_id = LR$IDX_ID;
                commit;

            END;                       

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE C1;
        COMMIT;
    End ;
    /
```

Comment: This is right solution (WO) How To Resolve Rebuild Help Search Index Errors Due To Duplicate Index Name? (Doc ID 1369248.1)

Answer (score 1):

[1] Oracle Text: `Create Or Alter Index Fails With DRG-50857, ORA-27486 ( Doc ID 2497828.1 )`

`grant create` job to the user and then try to create the indexes, it should work.

I had a situation of changing index sync parameter from `('SYNC (on commit)')` to `('SYNC (EVERY "SYSDATE+15/1440")')`, as this will automatically use a Oracle job, the schema should have create job privilege.

Answer (score 0):

it's not an answer basically, for those who get a slightly different error (i'm on Oracle 12c) during create index and right after drop index statements:

```
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50857: oracle error in drvxtab.create_index_tables
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 171
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 316
```

there seems to be a time lag (or something else) between drop of the index, and the cleanup of the related data from the CTXSYS tables (but i didn't need any commit statements). so for me, executing drop of the index AGAIN and running the same create statement AGAIN resolved the issue (the second create runs OK)